# Officejet j4580 doesn't print under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hp-officejet

I have an Officejet j4580 which worked fine under Windows XP and Windows 7. Recently, I upgraded the computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10 in-place, after burning the Windows 10 upgrade to a DVD and running the upgrade from it. Ever since then, I can't print anything.

I installed the full software package (OJ_AIO_J4500_Full_Win_WW_140_404-4.exe) for Windows 10 from [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Officejet-J4000-All-in-One-Printer-series/3645081/model/3645099). The first attempt failed, in a similar way to [this issue](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Stuck-on-quot-Checking-System-quot-during-driver/m-p/2988339/highlight/true#M107161). After this was solved, the installer failed at the end of the process, with the error log indicating that a device with the same name already exists. So I uninstalled the device driver (all through the installer I downloaded from the first link), manually removed the printer from Devices and Printers, and installed again by the directions (unplugging the printer, and then plugging it again at the end of the installer). This time, the installation went smoothly. Still, no print. So I uninstalled everything and installed everything again (except the Bing crapware), but that didn't help.

The printer doesn't print from applications, or from the "Print Test Page" button in printer properties in Devices and Printers. The hardware is working and the communication with the computer is working, because the HP software was able to make the printer print three different test pages: the trumpet image, the fax test result, and printer test page. When I try to print, the ink level indicator pops in the corner, the page shows in the spool window, but nothing comes out of the printer. It's as if something swallows the print somewhere along the print stack.

HP Print and Scan Doctor passes all tests with no error. I went through the steps [here](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Officejet-4500-All-in-One-Printer-Series---G510/3919445/document/c04714314).

I appreciate any help.

**Update**

Thanks to the advice from @Epoxy, I found in the event viewer this error:

> The document Print Document, owned by Tsahi Asher, failed to print on printer HP Officejet J4500 Series. Try to print the document again, or restart the print spooler. 
>   Data type: NT EMF 1.008. Size of the spool file in bytes: 131072. Number of bytes printed: 0. Total number of pages in the document: 1. Number of pages printed: 0. Client computer: \TSAHI. Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 2147500037. Unspecified error

Comment: Did you try rebooting and/or restarting the print spooler service? Also, a good place to check printing issues is the "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService%4Admin.evtx" log.

Comment: Some suggestions related to the print spooler not working, might be your issue.....http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/build-9879-print-spooler-service-stops-working/7433653b-90cc-430c-baa4-7959f265e947

Comment: You describe successfully printing three different test pages.  Just to confirm, that was from the driver software on the computer, not self-tests built into the printer?

Comment: @fixer1234, the prints are from the installer software and from HP Print and Scan Doctor. not from a normal application (i tried notepad) nor from the "Print Test Page" button.

Comment: @CConard96 the computer was restarted several times while trying to solve this. where is that log?

Comment: If you think it is a problem with the system/driver/application, use the event viewer to view logs. Press start menu, type eventvwr.msc and press enter to open it. Printers also maintain a log, not every printing system. You can consult the documentation to find it.

Comment: @CConard96 I found that log, it has the same error from the event viewer (naturally), I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I "fixed" the problem by reverting back to Windows 7 from backup, and everything went back to normal. I initially tried the "Restore Windows 7" feature of Windows 10, but then the HP installer refused to install the utility programs, thinking they are already installed. So instead of fighting it, I've overwritten it.